# Window shape change not working properly in kivy?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I want to change shape by default not on click, but I am not able to do so, some error pop-up every time, Please Help!

Second, In the following code when I click 2 time then it comes in shape please explain about it. Or what should I do to change shape in One click.

Here is my shape image,
'100x100.png'

[image]

Here is my code,

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'shaped', 1)

from kivy.resources import resource_find
alpha_shape = resource_find('100x100.png')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import (
    BooleanProperty,
    StringProperty,
    ListProperty,
)

Builder.load_string('''
<Root>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        text: 'alpha_shape'
        on_release: app.shape_image = app.alpha_shape

''')


class Root(BoxLayout):
    pass


class ShapedWindow(App):
    shape_image = StringProperty('', force_dispatch=True)

    def on_shape_image(self, instance, value):
        Window.size = (100, 100)
        Window.shape_image = self.alpha_shape
        Window.borderless = True
        Window.shape_mode = 'binalpha'
        Window.shape_color_key = [1, 1, 1, 1]
        Window.shape_cutoff = True
        
    def build(self):
        self.alpha_shape = alpha_shape
        return Root()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the one of the right way to solve your problem is using the [Clock](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html) into the `build` method.
I would do it this way:

```py
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'shaped', 1)

from kivy.resources import resource_find
alpha_shape = resource_find('10x10.png')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock


Builder.load_string('''
<Root>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        text: 'alpha_shape'
        on_release: app.shape_image(self)
''')


class Root(BoxLayout):
    pass


class ShapedWindowApp(App):
    shape_image = StringProperty('', force_dispatch=True)

    def build(self):
        Window.size = (100, 100)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.set_shape)
        return Root()

    def set_shape(self, *args):   
        Window.shape_image = alpha_shape
        Window.borderless = True
        Window.shape_mode = 'default'
        Window.shape_cutoff = True

    def shape_image(self,*args):
        print("on_release()")
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ShapedWindowApp().run()
```